# PHP proc_open unable to write to stdin of a program

Tags: php, c, pipe

I wanted to try a simple example of PHP proc_open. I have a C program with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a*a);
    return 0;
}
```

and the PHP file has:

```
$filename3='start D:\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe';
$descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),  
  1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
);
$process=proc_open($filename3,$descriptorspec,$pipes);
if (is_resource($process))
{
    fwrite($pipes[0],"5");
    fclose($pipes[0]); 
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
}
```

Now if I run this php, it starts the Project2.exe in a separate window but it doesn't receive any inputs from the pipe and waits for user input, nor the contents of the stdout are printed.

But, if I remove the **start** keyword from the **filename3** variable and make it look like

```
$filename3='D:\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe
```

and run the PHP file, the C program finishes running in the background and I'm able to view the contents of the stdout in the webpage.

I want to launch the program separately and make it receive its inputs from the PHP file. Is it possible?